# supply a filename for a file-like object created by urlopen() or requests.get()

Tags: python, python-requests, telegram

I am building a Telegram bot using a [Telepot](http://telepot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library. To send a picture downloaded from Internet I have to use [sendPhoto](http://telepot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#telepot.Bot.sendPhoto) method, which accepts a file-like object.

Looking through the docs I found this advice:

> If the file-like object is obtained by `urlopen()`, you most likely have to supply a filename because Telegram servers require to know the file extension.

So the question is, if I get my filelike object by opening it with `requests.get` and wrapping with `BytesIO` like so:

```
res = requests.get(some_url)
tbot.sendPhoto(
    messenger_id,
    io.BytesIO(res.content)
)
```

how and where do I supply a filename?

Comment: Does the library accept taking a filename as an argument? If not - file like objects have a 'name' attribute - setting that may be enough.

Comment: @JonClements what if the library only accepts filename? Do we have to store the memory file in a temp disk file?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You would supply the filename as the object's `.name` attribute.

Opening a file with `open()` has a .name attribute.

```
>>> local_file = open("file.txt")
>>> local_file
<open file 'file.txt', mode 'r' at ADDRESS>
>>> local_file.name
'file.txt'
```

Where opening a url does not. Which is why the documentation specifically mentions this.

```
>>> import urllib
>>> url_file = urllib.open("http://example.com/index.html")
>>> url_file
<addinfourl at 44 whose fp = <open file 'nul', mode 'rb' at ADDRESS>>
>>> url_file.name
AttributeError: addinfourl instance has no attribute 'name'
```

In your case, you would need to create the file-like object, and give it a `.name` attribute:

```
res = requests.get(some_url)
the_file = io.BytesIO(res.content)
the_file.name = 'file.image'

tbot.sendPhoto(
    messenger_id,
    the_file
)
```