# python - Open filelike object by filename

Tags: android, python, kivy, iostream, bytesio

I want to create a filelike object that will later be opened by its filename. Is it possible to do that? I'm looking for something like this:

```
import io

fileLikeObject = io.BytesIO()
fileLikeObject.write((b"randomContent")
fileLikeObject.name = "someFilename.txt"

sameFileAsbefore = open("someFilename.txt", "rb")
sameFileAsbefore.read()
```

I've looked at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42809451/supply-a-filename-for-a-file-like-object-created-by-urlopen-or-requests-get), but the file is not accessible by its name afterwards.

For completeness, what I want to specifically do is to generate a sinusoidal waveform and play in an Android environment. Here is a code adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44089196/kivy-doesnt-play-sound-file-the-first-time-play-is-called).

```
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.button import Button
import time


# Wave parameters
fs = 44100 # sampling frequency
duration = 2 # seconds

# Generating waveforms
timePoints = np.linspace(0, duration, duration*fs)
sineWave = np.sin(2 * np.pi * 440 * timePoints) # 440 Hz
outdata = np.transpose(np.tile(volume*outputWave, (2,1)))

class MyLabel(Button):
    def on_release(self):
        start_time = time.time()
        self.play_sound()
        print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

    def play_sound(self):

        bytes_out = io.BytesIO()
        wavfile.write(bytes_out, fs, outdata)
        bytes_out.seek(0)

        sound = SoundLoader.load(bytes_out) # only loads by filename :/
        sound.seek(0)

        if sound:
            print("Sound found at %s" % sound.source)
            print("Sound is %.3f seconds" % sound.length)
            sound.play()

runTouchApp(MyLabel(text="Press me for a sound"))
```

I'm also open to other solutions that allow me to play machine-generated sounds on Android. Thanks for helping!

Comment: So write the data to a file?

Comment: What i understood is that you need to load sound from memory and there is no direct way to do it, i think a cheap hack would be to create a local tmp directory where you save these files and load them, then clean it on 'app.on_stop'.

Answer (score 0):

As the saying goes, "premature optimization is the source of all evil", right?

Based on @fins' comment, I've created temporary files to store the audio using the library [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html). It automatically destroys the file when it is closed.

Here's the working version for what I've posted in the question:

```
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from scipy.io import wavfile
import time
import tempfile
import numpy as np

# Wave parameters
fs = 44100 # sampling frequency
duration = 2 # seconds

# Generating waveforms
timePoints = np.linspace(0, duration, duration*fs)
sineWave = np.sin(2 * np.pi * 440 * timePoints) # 440 Hz
outdata = np.transpose(np.tile(sineWave, (2,1)))

class MyLabel(Button):
    def on_release(self):
        start_time = time.time()
        self.play_sound()
        print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

    def play_sound(self):

        f = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix = '.wav', delete=True)
        wavfile.write(f, fs, outdata)
        f.seek(0)

        sound = SoundLoader.load(f.name)

        if sound:
            print("Sound found at %s" % sound.source)
            print("Sound is %.3f seconds" % sound.length)
            sound.play()

        f.close()

runTouchApp(MyLabel(text="Press me for a sound"))
```